# How to programmatically add self signed certificate for making a HTTPS request from java code?

Tags: java, ssl, https, get, ssl-certificate

Following code snippet is to get `JSon` response from a `HTTP` URL:

```
private static void getJson(String location) {
    try {
        try {
            createSSLSocket();
            URL url = new URL(
                    "https://abc.com/key/one");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But it is throwing `SSLHandshaking` exception because i didn't added self signed certification exception to the code. I have done this in `C#` but not in java. What steps should i perform? Need your suggestion :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the server certificate is self-signed and that's why the connection failed? What is the failure reason contained in the SSLHandshakeException?

Comment: @jcs Yes the server side connection is self signed and here is the error:`unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: @Jcs can we do it progammatically?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer with a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the `HttpsURLConnection` socket factory to accept all certificate without any validation:

```
private class TrustAll implements X509TrustManager
{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException
    {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException
    {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
    {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new TrustAll() }, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
```

**UPDATE**

You just have to call this code once at the start of the application. All HTTPS connections opened with `URL.openConnection()` will use this socket factory. Another solution could be adding this code in the `createSSLSocket()` method body.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but would you please tell me how should i connect to getJson method (written in question)?

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually you do not have much code to change.

Comment: So after that can i use `HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`?

Comment: Yes, the SSL socket factory is set globally

Comment: Note that this technique is radically insecure. You should adopt @cyon's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

To add trust for a self signed certificate, you can create a `truststore` java keystore file and set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property to point at this file. The `openConnection` method will check the truststore to see if the certificate can be trusted.

To create a truststore file you can use the `keytool` command which is part of the JDK and should be in your `JAVA_HOME/bin` directory.

```
keytool -import -file yourcert.cert -alias abc -keystore truststore.jks
```

The command will prompt you for a password which you will need if you want to edit the truststore. After entering the password it will create a `truststore.jks` file. To programmatically set the truststore in Java you can either pass it as a property with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/truststore.jks` or you can call `System.setProperty`

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/truststore.jks");
```

To have a look at ssl properties used by Java have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).