# Programmatically add cacerts file to truststore

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-security

In my Spring boot application, I need to call an API (`GET: https://anotherserver.com/api`) on another server. The server admin gave me a file named `cacerts`(no extension), and told me to import the file using VM options every time I start my Spring boot application.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\k26342\Downloads\cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

It did work. Now I want to write some code to do so instead of using VM options but I have no idea how. I found some posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775408/programmatically-add-a-self-signed-certificate-to-your-keystore-truststore) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889058/programmatically-import-ca-trust-cert-into-existing-keystore-file-without-using)) but the posts are about `keystore` or `X509Certificate` which I think are different from my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the correct option to set a truststore. You can also set it using `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);` or configure a truststore for a specific connection loading keystore dinamically. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/6371459

Comment: @pedrofb Thanks. Your solution is correct. I just need to add two lines of code:   `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath);  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword)`.    Please post an answer if you have time and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom truststore is a correct option to set the trusted certificates accepted in a SSL connection. You can also set the default trustore using `System.setProperty()` instead of `-D`

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword)
```

Alternatively you can configure a truststore for a specific connection loading keystore dinamically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/6371459

Answer (score 0):

System.setproperty works, but I think it is better to load the truststore via Java code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58695061/1938507

Answer (score -2):

Although you should be careful fiddling with JRE installation, you can *programmatically* install a new cacerts file in the JRE installation with something like:

```java
File from = new File("C:\\Users\\k26342\\Downloads\\cacerts");
File to = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "security" + File.separator + "cacerts");
Files.copy(from, to);
```

Note 1: It is recommended to backup the original cacerts file first.

Note 2: There can be security constraints stopping you from above if you are not running the code as administrator.

Comment: I disagree with this option. In addition to the problems you mention **you may be affecting other applications and causing a security issue**. You also do not know if `java.home` is pointing to tomcat's JDK. And changes will occur after the next start

Comment: @pedrofb Agree it is not best practice, but OP did not want to use `-D` argument or one of the linked solutions.

Comment: I did not see _It did work_. In any case OP it is not pointing in the right direction.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea