# AWS DocumentDB TLS connection with Java

Tags: aws-documentdb

I am facing problems connecting with my DocumentDB cluster with plain Java over TLS/SSL

The procedure I followed as per the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect.html#w139aac29c11c13b5b9) is this:

I downloaded the `.pem` file from AWS and copied in the root of my java project, from where I executed:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -alias certAlias -keystore rds-ca-certs -storepass keyStorePassword
```

This has created the `rds-ca-certs`at the root of my project which now looks like this:

[image]

And, the java code in Main.java is:

```
package com.example.documentdb;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;


public final class Main {
    private Main() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String template = "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=%s";
        String username = "myUsernameInCluster";
        String password = "myPasswordInCluster";
        String clusterEndpoint = "mycluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017";
        String readPreference = "secondaryPreferred";
        String connectionString = String.format(template, username, password, clusterEndpoint, readPreference);

        String keystore = "rds-ca-certs";
        String keystorePassword = "keyStorePassword";

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keystorePassword);

        MongoClientURI clientURI = new MongoClientURI(connectionString);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientURI);

        MongoDatabase testDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> numbersCollection = testDB.getCollection("numbers");

        Document doc = new Document("name", "pi").append("value", 3.14159);
        numbersCollection.insertOne(doc);

        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = numbersCollection.find().iterator();
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }
}
```

It gives me this ugly error:

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Interestingly, when I use the mongo CLI to connect over SSL/TLS, like this:

```
mongo --ssl --host mycluster.node.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username myUsernameInCluster --password myPasswordInCluster
```

It works perfectly, so I have discarded a networking issue and I think the problem is in the Java code itself or in the `keytool` command executed.

Additionally, with TLS *disabled* in the cluster this [java code provided by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect.html#w139aac29c11c17b5b9) (that only differs in the keystore configuration) works.

PD: I know there are a bunch of other questions regarding SSL/TLS connection with AWS DocumentDB, but none of them address my issue specifically. Moreover, I have also checked plain mongodb TLS/SSL connection questions and the process differ so they are not valid for me.

Comment: I don't think you are actually loading the trust store .. try `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/keystore.jks`   Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138574/java-path-to-truststore-set-property-doesnt-work .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790981/load-java-trust-store-at-runtime-after-jvm-have-been-launched . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore/5871301 . You can also import the aws rds bundle into your java trust store

Comment: @Yan as the trust store is in the root of the project, i simply call it by its name. In any case, I have tested that with an absolute path also and the same problem happens. I am interested on what you said about importing the aws rds bundle into java trust store directly because that wouldn't required the keytool configuration and everything is done by code, right? can you share some details about this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the process of importing the certificates within the **bundle**, under the same alias.

So I have had to *stop* using the bundled option (rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) and start using this one [rds-ca-2019-root.pem](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem)

After importing the keystore using the following command:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file rds-ca-2019-root.pem -alias rds19 -keystore rds-ca-certs -storepass keyStorePassword
```

Connectivity with the database under TLS was achieved.

Comment: That's great that you worked it out.  That makes sense.  Usually, you would import just the root ca certificate so this way the server would present the chain and you trust the root of it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was having a hard time trying to connect my EMR Spark cluster to documentdb , and this solved it.

Comment: My pleasure @FábioJunqueira

Comment: @Arcones  Can you please share complete solution? steps, folder structure and code? I am facing same issue and not able to resolve

Comment: @sidgate IIRC, I didn't change the folder structure from what it's reported in the question

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I was having a hard time finding a fix. However I had confusions between these root certificate, intermediate certificate, chain of trust. If anyone has the same refer below link to grasp a basic idea on this. https://aboutssl.org/root-certificates-vs-intermediate-certificates/#:~:text=Root%20certificates%20are%20the%20Certificate,who%20offers%20an%20intermediate%20root.

Comment: Same issue for me, even with your solution, not able to get it working. I try to connect to my documentdb through ssh tunnel. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the AWS provided certificate to the java's trust store then java will trust requests to AWS service by default.
You will have to find your java cacerts file. Depending on your OS and java version it should be in `..lib/security/cacerts`.
I am using OSX and it was in
`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

Then you cause keytool to import it the default java keystore password is change it:

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts  -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias aws-rds  -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

To check if the certificate was imported you can use:
`keytool -list -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep  aws`

Post back if that worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. I ended up opening a AWS support case, the problem was related with the process of importing the certificates within the bundle, under the same alias. I will post the procedure that helped me to solve it in a moment. Thanks for your help in any case

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hungbang/spring-boot-aws-docdb
I have created a sample to connect to amazon docdb from spring boot with SSL enabled.