# AWS Lambda: Is it possible to create keystore/jks from base64 decoded string in runtime of aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a question related to  aws lambda.
I have restriction do not store jks and base64 string inside git project. So I have to use hashicorp vault for this purpose.
But aws lambda run jar as part of it runtime and need to be precompiled with keystore.

Also in my case I use terraform for deploying and configuring lambda.

So question is if I provide with terraform ENV variable base64 encoded certificate, can I create within lambda in runtime JKS keystore and then use it to authorize on 3rd party service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load java trust store at runtime - after jvm have been launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790981/load-java-trust-store-at-runtime-after-jvm-have-been-launched)

Comment: no, I need create it first at runtime and store to the file system. And question is it possible to do within aws lambda runtime